# Relativistic Rocket Equation Derivation

Tags: special-relativity, antimatter, rocket-science

Could somebody help me derive [this equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter_rocket#Modified_relativistic_rocket_equation)?

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{M}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}v(1-v_\mathrm{ex}\frac{v}{c^2})}{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})(-v_\mathrm{ex}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+(1-a)v+av_\mathrm{ex})}
$$
This is purportedly the relativistic rocket equation when accounting for annihilation to usable exhaust. To quote Wikipedia, " $a$ is the fraction of the original (on board) propellant mass (non-relativistic) remaining after annihilation (i.e., $a=0.22$ for the charged pions)."

I can see that this reduces to the usual relativistic rocket equation when $a=0$:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{M}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v_\mathrm{ex}(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}
$$

However, I can't seem to derive the above equation. Here's my attempt (which succeeds for the normal relativistic rocket equation):

In the COM frame, the rocket's initial mass is $M+\mathrm{d}M$. Its final mass is $M$ and its velocity in this frame is $\mathrm{d}v'$. Let's say the exhaust has mass $\mathrm{d}m$ and velocity $v_\mathrm{ex}$, so if all the exhaust were usable, energy conservation would give
$$(M+\mathrm{d}M)c^2-Mc^2=\frac{c^2\,\mathrm{d}m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_\mathrm{ex}^2}{c^2}}}
$$
(to first order in $\mathrm{d}v'$). However, in reality, not all of the exhaust is usable. Let's say only a fraction $\alpha$ of the energy loss $c^2\,\mathrm{d}M$ is captured by beamed core exhaust pions:
$$
\alpha c^2\,\mathrm{d}M=\frac{c^2\,\mathrm{d}m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_\mathrm{ex}^2}{c^2}}}.
$$

Okay, now let's look at momentum. For simplicity's sake, we'll assume all the useless energy is radiated symmetrically, so there's no effect on momentum. The final momentum of the rocket is $M\,\mathrm{d}v'$ (to first order in $\mathrm{d}v'$), and that of the exhaust is
$$
-\frac{v_\mathrm{ex}\,\mathrm{d}m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_\mathrm{ex}^2}{c^2}}}
=-\alpha v_\mathrm{ex}\,\mathrm{d}M
$$

But doesn't this then mean that

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}M}{M}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}v'}{\alpha v_\mathrm{ex}}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\alpha v_\mathrm{ex}(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}
$$
when we go back to the lab frame? I get nothing resembling the equation at the start.

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a reference for that equation. Did you look at it? (I haven’t, but I would expect to find a derivation there.)

Comment: Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and not a "do my homework for me" question.